# Can't cross-compile/run valgrind on ARMv7 machine

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, valgrind

all.
I am trying to cross-compile valgrind in PC x86_64 Fedora35 to ARMv7 (cortex-a8) embedded system running Linux 2.6.37.
When I compiled and ran version 3.20.0 it said "FATAL: Kernel too old" although Valgrind states that any kernel younger than 2.6.31 is ok.
ChatGPT recommended to take older version 3.8.1 and I tried.
But compilation with the same parameters fails - machine armv7 is not recognized.
I also tried armv5 but the same result.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

For those coming after me with this task, below is the way to do this.
To cross-compile Valgrind 3.20.0 I used the following script:

```
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
export CCFLAGS="-mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon"
export LDFLAGS=" -Wl,--rpath=/lib/glibc.2.23,--dynamic-linker=/lib/glibc.2.23/ld-linux-armhf.so.3"
./configure --host=armv7-linux-gnueabihyf --target=armv7-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/opt/FS_HDVR/opt
make
make install
```

When this finished successfully, I need to run the following command to execute MyApp under Valgrind:
`export VALGRIND_LIB=/opt/libexec/valgrind; /opt/bin/valgrind MyApp`
Note that most probably (I am not sure) the glibc should correspond to the cross-compiler in use.
Anyway, now I can run Valgrind with my application(s).